# Segue Trouble - Making New View Controller Fully Replace Old VC

Tags: swift

I have a 'main menu' view controller with links to different types of calculators.  When I click on the link to a new calculator, the "main menu" can still be seen behind the new page.  I would like to have the calculator completely replace the main menu when I click the link.  I've tried modifying the segue on the storyboard, but cannot figure out how to fix this.

[Storyboard settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ylvnt.png)

[Purple outlines the main menu hiding behind the new view controller.  I want this to go away.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/N2FlC.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will need to embed the "Main Menu" into a Navigation Controller. If you don't do this, no matter what type of segue (which you refer to as a "link") you use, that outline will always be visible. To do this, select the Main Menu View controller from the storyboard, and click a little button on the bottom right of the screen looking like this: [image: down arrow in square icon]

and select "Navigation Controller".

Next, you can do one of the following:

Click on each segue from the main menu to each type of calculator, and in the attributes inspector, change the "Kind" (Which you currently have as "Present as Popover" to "Show".

Alternatively, if you like the way the segue slides up, and would just like it to be full screen,change the "Kind" setting to "Present Modally", and change the "Presentation" setting (under "Kind") to "Full Screen", for as many of the segues as you'd like.